# Spring boot 2 upgrade - spring boot data jpa saveAll() very slow

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-boot

I use mysql with hibernate and spring boot data jpa (spring-boot-starter-data-jpa and mysql-connector-java). Recently I upgraded my spring boot project from 1.5 to 2.0. The API of the spring data CrudRepository to save an iterable has changed form save() to saveAll(). I made the changes in the code and it works but it is very slow:

- insert 10 items -> 2 times slower (49ms -> 95ms)
- insert 100 items -> 6 times slower (132ms -> 840ms)
- insert 1000 items -> 10 times slower (792ms -> 8028ms)
- insert 10000 items -> 15 times slower (4912ms -> 73542ms)
- insert 100000 items -> 22 times slower (32042ms -> 712702ms)

I have tested the inserts of both spring versions with an empty table. The mysql server version hasn't change: 5.7.21 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)

I need to insert ~2M items daily so this slowdown is dramatically. This is my configuration:

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/service?useSSL=false&rewriteBatchedStatements=true
spring.datasource.username = service
spring.datasource.password = service
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=5

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=50
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_inserts=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_updates=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_versioned_data=true
```

Does anybody know what changed with the update and how to speed it up again?

Comment: AFAIK that method will insert one by one each entity into the database so you have to do it with batch insert. https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-do-batch-processing-with-jpa-and-hibernate/

Comment: I tested the batch insert method but it has no effect. The manual implementation is as slow as the the saveAll method. Interesting is that the manual batch insert method with spring boot 1.5 is as fast as the old save method from the CrudRepository. Maybe there are some basic architectural changes with the update to the version 2.0.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this, or to at least figure out what the problem is/was?

Answer (score 0):

in application.properties set spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.generate_statistics = true

```
hibernate:
  generate_statistics: true
```

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-batch-inserts